# While running the Linux vm on a Chromebook, what do I have to do to compile and run a C++ program?

Tags: c++, virtual-machine, chromebook

So I was creating my first *(noob-ish)* C++ program, but when I tried to compile it gave me this.

```
-bash: g++: command not found
-----@penguin:~$
```

And I don't know how to install or fix it.

Comment: Depends on the Linux distribution. There should be a package manager that'll suck GCC down, install, and configure it for you.

Comment: no, it doesn't. That's for windows, and I'm on my Chromebook. for robert.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your Linux distro, but you could try `sudo apt install g++` and `sudo yum install g++` - one of those will probably work.  You may also have a software setup/installer/browser app - see if your desktop has a app search function or menu you can find it in....

Comment: nvm still troubleshooting

Comment: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/09/11/cpp-development-chromebook-chrome-os/

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a chromebook, so I cannot verify:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install software-properties-common
 
sudo apt install gcc g++
```

Comment: I have a chromebook, I verify it works