# Code::Blocks build and run is not working on Chromebook

Tags: c++, debian, codeblocks, chromebook

Whenever I try to build and run any C++ code (I didn’t try it with other programming languages) in [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks), a prompt pops up saying this:

> it seems that the project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?"

with three options of <kbd>No</kbd>, <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, and <kbd>Yes</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot of the dialog with buttons "No", "Cancel", and "Yes"]

When I click <kbd>Yes</kbd>, the prompt closes, and it says this in the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in main (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c /home/sudo/codeblocks/main/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/main obj/Debug/main.o
/bin/sh: 1: g++: not found
Process terminated with status 127 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

[image]

I use [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) on a Chromebook I have tried some solutions, but so far nothing has worked. I don't know if this matters, but the file is in a console application project or something.

Comment: Did you install g++? Can you locate g++ in the bin directory (e.g. using `find /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin -name g++`)? [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/871d0b14b3588d6b)

Comment: (Note: The screenshots [are OK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) as ***the text is also provided***.)

Comment: Or was the intent to hide the screenshots?

Comment: @Peter really? If there’s text then all screenshots do is slow down the loading of the page for everyone

Comment: @PeterMortensen I had no intent to hide the screenshots but after reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/ I dont think i need the images, also thanks for correcting the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install `g++` to compile C++ code. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902093/while-running-the-linux-vm-on-a-chromebook-what-do-i-have-to-do-to-compile-and), you can use these commands to install it:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install software-properties-common

sudo apt install gcc g++
```

Comment: i only did  `sudo apt install g++` and it worked